# Converter issue with jOOQ when mapping nested records

Tags: jooq

I have two basically identical queries, one using `multiset` and the other using `row`, but they behave differently with regard to converting from SQL datatype to Java/Kotlin.

For example, here's the `multiset`:

```
multiset(
    select(
        CALENDAR_ENTRIES.ID,
        CALENDAR_ENTRIES.EVENT_DATE
    )
        .from(CALENDAR_ENTRIES)
        .where(cond)
).`as`("calendar_entry")
    .convertFrom { r: Result<Record2<Long, LocalDateTime>> ->
        r.map(
            Records.mapping { id: Long?, eventDate: LocalDateTime? ->
                CalendarEntry(id, eventDate!!)
            }
        )
    }
```

and here's the `row`:

```
row(
    CALENDAR_ENTRIES.ID,
    CALENDAR_ENTRIES.EVENT_DATE
)
    .mapping { id: Long?, eventDate: LocalDateTime ->
        CalendarEntry(id, eventDate)
    }
```

For argument's sake, assuming the DB has 1 record, with `eventDate` being (as a String)
'2022-02-21 09:30:00'.

With the first query, I successfully get my `Field<List<CalendarEntry>>` instance. With the second query (`row()`), I get "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-02-21 09:30:00' could not be parsed at index 10".

It seems that jOOQ is able to correctly apply a converter for the `multiset` call, but not the `row` call. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using PostgreSQL.

You probably ran into this bug here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13117. The difference in behaviour is explained by the fact that as of jOOQ 3.16:

- `MULTISET` gets emulated using `JSONB` functionality
- `ROW` gets

  - emulated using `JSONB` functionality when nested within multiset
  - implemented natively using PostgreSQL `ROW` expressions when used at the top level

Bug https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13117 seems to affect also top level `ROW` types, not just UDTs. It has been fixed recently, and might be backported to 3.16 and 3.15.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I am using PostgreSQL. I'll update to a snapshot (or build locally if needed) and retry. Thanks!

Comment: @jasondlee: Snapshots are available from here, if you're licensed: https://www.jooq.org/download/versions

Comment: The SNAPSHOT did the trick. Thanks!